# Why is lexical binding not working in this example in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I copy-pasted this example from the emacs wiki: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding#toc2

The wiki says that the printed thing should be 1, but for me it prints 2, indicating that lexical binding doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue why that might be?

I'm on Emacs v26. Debian.

Here is what is literally in my buffer. I am evaluating it with `M-x eval-buffer`.

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t;-*-

(let ((a 1))                            ; binding (1)
  (let ((f (lambda () (print a))))
    (let ((a 2))                        ; binding (2)
      (funcall f))))
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You have to close the file and reopen in in order for the file variable to be set. WIthout that, `lexical-binding` is set to nil by default.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set `lexical-binding` as a file variable. That gets set when the file is opened, so if you just add the text to the file without closing it and reopening it, the value of `lexical-binding` will still be nil (do `C-h v lexical-binding RET` and see for yourself). So you are using dynamic binding and you get 2 for the value.

If you close and reopen the file, the file variable *will* be set (check it!) and when you evaluate the form, you will get 1.